# How do I know which version of RichFaces I am running?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, richfaces

Can you tell me how to find out which version of Richfaces I am running?

I need to know if I have jQuery already installed so perhaps a way to test that would help as an answer as well.

I am using Version: 2.1.0.GA of JBOSS Developer Studio.. if that helps.

Answer (score 7):

This should help: http://mkblog.exadel.com/2010/03/getting-richfaces-version-in-runtime/

Answer (score 1):

In JBoss developer studio (which is based on Eclipse), right-click your project and choose

> Build Path > Configure Build Path

There you have the Libraries tab, where all libraries are listed. Look for richfaces and see the version.

Another way - when you deploy your application, check the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. There should be the richfaces jar there, with version included.