# Tag Library supports namespace , but no tag was defined for name : ajax

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF1.2 + Richface 3.3.3 . I was trying to design a column filter which filters all the rows containing that particular string. I tried implementing the example on the following page : http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=dataTable&sample=tableFiltering&skin=blueSky

But I am getting an error "Tag Library supports namespace , but no tag was defined for name : ajax"

How do I go about it.

Comment: Put your code in here so we can see whats wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at a showcase for RichFaces 4.3, showcase for RichFaces 3.3.x is [here](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/).

`<a4j:ajax>` is not part of RF 3, hence the error. In RF 3 the component is called `<a4j:support>`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the error

> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag
>   was defined for name: XYZ

is an indicator that your version of richfaces is either earlier than the  introduction of  this component in the framework, or later than the removal of this component from the framework. Basically, that component doesn't exist in the richfaces version you are using.

Here is how to check your richfaces version: [How do I know which version of RichFaces I am running?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680165/how-do-i-know-which-version-of-richfaces-i-am-running)

You can go to http://richfaces.jboss.org/download/archive , download the jar with the version you are using, unzip it,and search for a class with the same name as your component. In the unzipped jar, open the folder `artifacts`.

Within `artifacts/ui`, unzip the jars `richfaces-components-api`  and `richfaces-components-ui`.

Within `artifacts/framework`, unzip the jars `richfaces-core-api` and `richfaces-core-imp`.

In these 4 locations, there is an `/org` folder with a `richfaces` subfolder. I think these are the only places where you can look for the component you want to use.